# Anonymous character at the beginning of a string

Tags: ruby, string, split

I have a text file that has an anonyomous character at the beginning of each line, like empty string but not blank, nor empty.

Example text:

> Q1

I tried various ways to remove that, but failed.

```
all_text = File.open(file_txt, 'r')
all_text.each do |text|
   text = text.gsub(/\r\n?/, "")
   # debug here
end

[1] pry(main)> text
=> "Q1"
[2] pry(main)> text.length
=> 3
```

`text` has three characters:

```
[3] pry(main)> text.split('')
=> ["", "Q", "1"]
```

Tried to remove the empty character with reject, but still it has length 3.

```
[4] pry(main)> text.split('').reject(&:empty?).length
=> 3
```

Tried to remove it with `slice!`

```
[5] pry(main)> text.slice!(0)
=> ""
[6] pry(main)> text.length
=> 2
```

but I think that's bad practice.

I have a lot of files of text, and I think not all files have an anonymous character at the beginning of each line, and the anonymous character may not only be at the beginning of a line.

How do I to know the type of the anonymous character? How can I remove that?

Comment: Look at the text file in a hex editor to see what's really there. Or look at `text.chars` and `text.bytes` in Ruby.

Comment: Do you mean [anomalous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anomalous)?

Comment: What is an "anonymous character"? I have never heard of such a thing. The term doesn't seem to have a widely-known accepted definition. If you use terms that are not well-known, you should generally provide a precise definition, so that we know what you are talking about. For example, the Unicode Consortium assigns a name to each and every character in the Unicode Character Set, so in that sense, something like an "anonymous character" simply does not exist at all, so I find it hard to understand how there could be one in your string. And what *is* that character anyway, that's the most …

Comment: … important information of all, which you have simply left out of your question. Also, what is a "type" of an anonymous character? Are you talking about a Unicode Property?

Answer (score 1):

They may be non-printable non-empty characters.

```
"\ufeff".inspect  # => looks like "\"\""
"\ufeff".empty?   # => false
```

You may want to inspect *your* character, and the underlying bytes first.

NOTE depending on your locale and stuff, ruby may reinterpret the bytes for encoding conversion. The safest option is is to use non-biased byte-oriented tool like `xxd`.

If that character is fixed or valid (like in the case of Unicode byte order mark), detecting it and working around should be possible.

Answer (score 0):

The question asks how the first character of each line can be removed from a file. It is technically possible to modify the file in place, but that would not be good practice. The usual procedure is to write the file without the offending characters to a new file. If desired, the original file can be removed and the new file renamed to the name of the original file. Give that it is exactly one character to be removed per line, for all lines, it doesn't matter if that character prints like a space or not. I will, however, use an example where the character to be skipped is a non-breaking space.

A different approach would be needed if only some lines began with the offending character or if multiple offending characters were to be removed at the beginning of some or all lines. In this case, one could construct an array of offending characters and use a regular expression to remove them at the beginning of each line.

Let's begin by constructing a file that has one non-breaking space at the beginning of each line.

```
str =<<_
\u00A0Now is the time for all
\u00A0good Rubiests to come to the
\u00A0aid of their bowling team
_

FNameIn = "test_in"

File.write(FNameIn, str)
  #=> 85
```

Confirm the file contents.

```
File.foreach(FNameIn) { |line| puts "|#{line.strip}|" }
  # | Now is the time for all|
  # | good Rubiests to come to the|
  # | aid of their bowling team|
```

Reading the file line-by-line and writing each line minus its first character to another file is straightforward.

```
FNameOut = "test_out"

File.open(FNameOut, "w+") do |f|
  File.foreach(FNameIn) { |line| f.puts(line[1..-1]) }
  f.close
end
```

Let's see what was written.

```
File.foreach(FNameOut) { |line| puts "|#{line.strip}|" }
  # |Now is the time for all|
  # |good Rubiests to come to the|
  # |aid of their bowling team|
```

See [IO::write](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-c-write), [IO::foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/IO.html#method-c-foreach) and [File::open](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/File.html#method-c-open). `IO` methods are commonly invoked on the class `File`, which is permitted because `File` is a subclass of `IO` (`File < IO #=> true`).